# Python print random line from file without repeat

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, random, text

I have a little program which prints random lines from a text file. I want to save the the already chosen lines in a list or something else, so it don't will repeat next time.

**Example**

> text_database.txt
>
> 1. This is a line
> 2. This is an other line
> 3. This is a test line
> 4. That sucks

This is an example to show that the output is random and the program repeats lines – it is **not** the direct output in the terminal:

```
This is a line
That sucks
That sucks
That sucks
This is a line
```

My code:

```
# Variable for text file
text_database = './text_database.txt'

...

with open (text_database) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    print(random.choice(lines))
```

What I tried:

```
with open (text_database) as f:
    lines_list = []
    lines = f.readlines()
    random_tmp = random.choice(lines)
    if random_tmp not in lines_list:
        lines_list.append(random_tmp)
        print(random_tmp)
```

It doesn't work and I need help. Thank you guys.

Comment: Is this printing one random line from the file when you run it and then the program ends? Just to be clear, you want to save which lines have been printed across different executions of the program? Edit: Else I dont see why its printing 5 times, not sure what the `elif` is surrounded by

Comment: It's a telegram bot and the messages will print on a thermal printer. So the program is running the hole time and it prints lines from the file when the program runs. The first code block works great. And yeah I want to save which lines have been printed, so the program will choose an other line next time. The output is just to show you that the program repeats the lines. It's NOT the direct output. It prints only one time. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You're not updating `lines_list`, is that the source of your problem? And it would be more efficient as a `set`, not a `list`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a REALLY messy solution but i have tested this beforehand

```
f = open(text_database, "r")

list = []
list_of_nums = []

for i in f:
    list.append(i)

elif command == '/random':

    randomNum = random.randint(0, len(list) - 1)

    def reRun():
        global randomNum
        for i in list_of_nums:

            if randomNum == i:
                randomNum = random.randint(0, len(list) - 1)
                reRun()


    reRun()
    list_of_nums.append(randomNum)

    print(list[randomNum])
```

What this code deos is go throgh all the lines in f and put them in a list. than it choses a random number bettween 0 and the lenght of the list and prints a random line corresponding to that number

Hope this helps! And welcome to stack overflow

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I'm right, the program will print a random line with possibility of duplication - I am right?

Comment: oh sorry now that i re read your question i now know what you want giv me a couple of minutes and ill edit it

Comment: i have soleved the issue but its really messy ill edit the post now

Answer (score 5):

```
from random import sample

file_name = "text_database.txt"
lines = open(file_name, "r").read().splitlines()

for line in sample(lines, k=len(lines)):
    print(line)
```

I use `.read().splitlines()` instead of `.readlines()` to purge the trailing whitespace (newlines) from each line. I could have also done:

```
lines = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in open(file_name, "r")]
```

Here is a description of `random.sample` from the documentation:

> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population
>   sequence. Used for random sampling without replacement.

Alternatively, you could have shuffled your list of lines, and then iterated over them.

EDIT - I think I understand now. How's this?

```
def main():

    from random import shuffle

    file_name = "text_database.txt"
    lines = open(file_name, "r").read().splitlines()
    shuffle(lines)

    sentinel = object()

    def command_random():
        try:
            line = lines.pop()
        except IndexError:
            print("There are no more lines in the file!")
        else:
            print(line)

    def command_quit():
        nonlocal sentinel
        sentinel = None

    commands = {
        "random": command_random,
        "quit": command_quit
    }

    while sentinel is not None:
        user_input = input("Please enter a command: ")
        command = commands.get(user_input)
        if command is None:
            continue
        command()

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Why do you use `splitlines()`, why do you use `sample(...`? Please a bit more explanations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The program doesn't repeat the lines. The problem is, it prints all lines from the file, but I just want to print one line from the file without duplication.

Comment: When you say "without duplication" you mean, you run the program once, it prints a random line, you run the program again, and it prints a different random line (one that hasn't been printed in previous executions of the program)?

Comment: No, I described it in the comments over it. It's a telegram bot and the program is running the hole time. I want to print a line from the file when I open a command. In this case `/random`. The next time when I run the command, I want to print a other line from the text file. Not the same.

Answer (score 3):

```
elif command == '/random':
    with open (text_database) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    while len(lines)>0:
        max_int = len(lines)-1 #update the len each loop as we remove one each time
        print(lines.pop(random.randint(0, max_int))) #pop a random value from the list
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is, that the program print all lines from the file without duplication. But I want to print only one line.

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your code is that if you encounter a line you've already displayed, you just return and do nothing.

What you can do with small tweaks to your code is to pick a new random line *until* you find one you haven't chosen already. This is done using the `while` block:

```py
# Variable for text file
text_database = './text_database.txt'
#List of already chosen lines
lines_list = []

# Elif instruction for random lines from file
elif command == '/random':
    with open (text_database) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        random_tmp = random.choice(lines)
        #while line has been chosen already, try to chose another one
        while random_tmp in lines_list:
            random_tmp = random.choice(lines)
        lines_list.append(random_tmp)
        print(random_tmp)
```

Note that there are some limitations to this code:

- the loop will run forever once all lines have been chosen
- it can be memory-consuming to remember the lines of text that have been chosen, instead you could remember the indexes of the lines you've chosen.

Answer (score 2):

try this solution it prints only one random line each time

```
import random
text_database = './text_database.txt'
lines_list = []
with open (text_database) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines_list.append(lines)
for item in lines_list:
    rand_item = item[random.randrange(len(item))]
print(rand_item)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the program print lines duplicated.

Comment: can you explain more hat you mean by duplicated?

Answer (score 1):

Hey this is a bit less messy and has all the features you asked for

```
f = open(text_database, "r")

list = []

for i in f:
    list.append(i)

elif command == '/random':

    random.shuffle(list)

    for i in list:

        print(i)
```

This gets all the lines in the file and shuffles them using pythons built in `random.shuffle` There is no chance the lines will repeat themself and it is fairly efficent